# Angular 9 Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular9

I'm learning Angular 9 and trying new things on it. Today i tried router-outlets with name property as shown in the below code.

**My template:**

```
<router-outlet name='list1'></router-outlet>
```

**My router module**

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "", component: DashboardComponent, children: [
            { path: "", outlet: "list1", data: { msg: "This is ITEMS LIST test1" }, loadChildren: () => import("../items-list/items-list.module").then(m => m.ItemsListModule) },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Now every thing is working fine but when i reload the page manually, my Angular app gets crashed. it shows me the error:

```
core.js:6260 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
    at getChildConfig (router.js:5910)
    at Recognizer.processSegmentAgainstRoute (router.js:5836)
    at Recognizer.processSegment (router.js:5783)
    at Recognizer.processSegmentGroup (router.js:5754)
    at router.js:5768
    at router.js:1917
    at forEach (router.js:1455)
    at mapChildrenIntoArray (router.js:1910)
    at Recognizer.processChildren (router.js:5763)
    at Recognizer.processSegmentAgainstRoute (router.js:5840)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41640)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

Please if anyone can help me out then it'll be really good for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, there. Can you please show the imports array inside the `@NgModule` decorator, of your routing.module.ts file?

Comment: hi @thisdotutkarsh, thanks for your response, this is my code of routing module

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

Comment: I think `  path: "", component: DashboardComponent, children: [
            { path: "", outlet: "list1", data: { msg: "This is ITEMS LIST test1" }, loadChildren: () => import("../items-list/items-list.module").then(m => m.ItemsListModule) },
        ]` both empty paths what causing the issue ... please provide any string as path and try again if did't work will check it for you later tonight

Comment: okay @HusseinAkar let me try it

Comment: @HusseinAkar it's not working btw i need router-outlets in same dashboard page so i can't set the path here, if i add it'll be in different page

Comment: Please could you provide abstract about what you want to achieve I found that you trying to use lazy loading for routes when lazy loading route and the component route are the same!! that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have a lazy loaded Dashboard component which has two columns A and B, both A and B containers should lazy load another components. This is what i'm trying to do. any good way to achieve this?

Comment: Please could you provide app-routing.module.ts ... if you could edit the question and add any additional info may help would be great .. I will fix your issue and post full working solution after that.

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work, you need to use an auxiliary outlet without a name. So in your component just use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and your router module file should look like this:

```js
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "", component: DashboardComponent, loadChildren: () => import("../items-list/items-list.module").then(m => m.ItemsListModule) },
        ]
    }
];
```